# Is there a way to bind actions to every keystroke that is NOT a certain keybinding on Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

There's events in Angular that are bound to keybinding or actions such as (focus), (blur), (keydown), etc.

There's a way to bind specific keybindings to certain keys too, such as (keydown.enter), (keydown.alt), etc.

Is there a way to make an event pop when it's NOT a certain keybinding?

For example, let's say I fire a certain even when I press enter on an input:

```
<input (keydown.enter)="onKeydown($event)">
```

Is there a way to fire a different method when it's NOT enter?

I know there's a way to just see if the Event is an Enter inside the method called by (keydown), but I was wondering if there was a way to do it like with specific keybindings, but instead excluding that specifc key.

Comment: I don't believe there's a specific event for the behaviour you want. If it's a behaviour you'll want in multiple places, I'd advise writing a Directive for it.

Comment: @WillAlexander yeah I'm finding myself thinking it's probably going to be the best alternative for it. Specific keybindings are after all a directive too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some like:

```
<input (keydown)="$event.key!='Enter' && fool($event)">
```

(if the first condition is false, don't executed the function `fool`)

Answer (score 1):

The `keydown.enter` event is the only shortcut provided by Angular. You have to bind your listener to the native `keydown` event and filter by key:

```
<input (keydown)="onKeydown($event)">

onKeydown(event) {
  if(event.key !== "Enter") {
    // Some logic
  }
}
```